# How to deserialize a java.time.Instant from string?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I'm sending a jsonobject to my rest api, one of the fields is of type date:

```
{
 creationDate: '2017-12-27T11:23:58+01:00'
}
```

I want to decode so I just do:

```
private final ObjectMapper mapper; //I take the default one

//...
objectMapper.readValue(message.getBody().toJSONString(), MyClass.clazz);
```

where:

```
public class MyClazz{
    ...
    private Instant creationDate;
}
```

But in the end I get:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant` from String "2017-12-27T11:23:58+01:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.Instant: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2017-12-27T11:23:58+01:00'

I checked my configuration but I'm importing every module I need:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConf {

@Bean
public JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule() {
    return new JavaTimeModule();
}

@Bean
public Jdk8Module jdk8TimeModule() {
    return new Jdk8Module();
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Why a JSONObjct you marshal yourself? You shouldn't need the modules (they are detected automatically) and you can let Spring do the conversion without using `JSONObject`. Just add `@RequestBody MyClazz value` to your controller. You probably need an addition `JsonFormat` annotation on the field to specify the format used.

Comment: It's a long story....normally I use pojos, but in this case I have to support generic objects whose fields I don't know

Comment: Well aparently you do no because you are deserializing to an object, so one-way or another you do know.

Comment: No, because I get the type from the object field, cast it, and then send it to a service...problem is that the generic type I'm casting to does not define fields

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the date format, it seems there is no feature in `JavaTimeModule` use custom format for `Instant` (unlike for `LocalDateTime`). A workaround is to override the instant deserializer:

```
@Bean
public JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule() {
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(Instant.class, new StdDeserializer<Instant>(Instant.class) {
        @Override
        public Instant deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            return OffsetDateTime.parse(jsonParser.readValueAs(String.class), formatter).toInstant();
        }
    });
    return javaTimeModule;
}
```

Comment: I got the jist of it but it still doesn't work...maybe it's a string format problem